# combinatorics- 10 digit code with at least one symbol

Tags: combinatorics

The question: How many $10$ character codes you can create using a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and 10 symbols (!@#$%...) with at least one symbol?

The correct answer: $72^{10}-62^{10}$, counting all possible combinations minus the combinations without any symbol

My way of thinking: I put to the first place a symbol ($10$ ways), for the rest 9 positions a put whatever I want ($72^9$), I multiply by 10 to get every possible position of the symbol. $10^2 \cdot 72^9$ 
What's wrong in my thinking? What am I double counting? Is there a way to find the same solution using my thinking?

Comment: Consider 11111111!!, which of the !'s is your "first place"?

Comment: that's why i multiplied by 10 to get every possible position of the symbol.

Comment: My point was there are two !'s, and either can be your "first place", which is the source of double counting.

Comment: There is an alternative route to find the same solution: for $i=1,\dots,10$ find the number of codes having exactly $i$ symbols, and then take the summation. Not recommended though.

Comment: @drhab Σ(62^10-n * 10^n )

Comment: @GeorgeF Your last formula is missing $\binom{10}n$ inside the summation, because the $n$ symbols can appear in any $n$ of the $10$ positions.

Comment: So the alternative method is

$$\sum_{i=1}^{10} \binom{10}{i}62^{10-i}\cdot10^i = \sum_{i=0}^{10} \binom{10}{i}62^{10-i}\cdot10^i - \binom{10}i62^{10} = (62+10)^{10} - 62^{10}$$

Given that you know binomial theorem, this is not too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight modification to your thinking:

Give up the "multiply by 10 to get every possible position of the symbol", but say the first symbol appears on position $i$, $1\le i \le 10$.

For each position $i$, each character before it has $62$ independent choices, and each character after it has $72$ independent choices. The number of choices is

$$\begin{align*}
N &= \sum_{i = 1}^{10} 62^{i-1}\cdot 10 \cdot 72^{10-i}\\
&= \sum_{j = 0}^{9} 62^{j}\cdot 10 \cdot 72^{9-j}\\
&= 10\cdot72^9\sum_{j=0}^{9}\left(\frac{62}{72}\right)^j\\
&= 10\cdot72^9\cdot\frac{1-(62/72)^{10}}{1-62/72}\\
&= 10\cdot \frac{72^{10}-62^{10}}{72-62}\\
&= 72^{10}-62^{10}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Ok, now it is clearer. thank you everyone